# How to evaluate a function in n variables in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

How do I evaluate a function in `n` variables in `numpy`? For simplicity, let `n = 3`. Consider the following example:

```
x, y, z = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100), numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100), numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100)

def F(a, b, c): # Test function in 3 variables
    return a + b + c

F_over_xyz = ... # How to get an array that contains F evaluated at all points in [0;1]³?
```

Somehow, I am also having a hard time wrapping my head around which shape the generated array would have?.

Answer (score 1):

A general way to get Cartesian product of any wanted number of `arrays` is:

```
np.stack(np.meshgrid(*arrays), axis=-1).reshape(-1, len(arrays))
```

So you could list all the points in `[0;1]³`:

```
import numpy as np
arrays = np.linspace(0, 1, 100), np.linspace(0, 1, 100), np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
list_of_points = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*arrays), axis=-1).reshape(-1, len(arrays))
```

Shape of `list_of_points` is `(1000000, 3)`: 1M points, 3 coordinates each.

Then you can calculate sum of coordinates like so:

```
np.sum(list_of_points, axis=1)
```

Comment: What if the applied function is more complicated?

Comment: @HerpDerpington You could use [np.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), however, it doesn't add performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
import numpy as np

nn = 4
x,y,z=np.linspace(0,1,nn),np.linspace(0,1,nn),np.linspace(0,1,nn)

def F(a, b, c): # Test function in 3 variables
    return a + b + c

# this creates your grid
xgrid,ygrid,zgrid = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

# output[i,j,k] will be F(xgrid[i,j,k],ygrid[i,j,k],zgrid[i,j,k])
output = F(xgrid,ygrid,zgrid)
```

Comment: That gives me a `MemoryError` for large `nn`... But that's probably my laptop's fault

Comment: That's very likely.  Perhaps one solution is to not create xgrid,ygrid,zgrid explicity. See if meshgrid can return one tuple (x,y,z) at a time or write your own equivalent function.

Comment: Maybe itertools.product is your friend here

Comment: @Nachiket I posted a faster variant of `itertools.product` in my solution

Comment: @Mathfux I didn't realise that. It seems to me you are computing `list_of_points` explicitly. `itertools.product` would compute them on the fly.